# Entering text in pre HTML tag using selenium

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am trying to enter text using selenium JAVA and there is **pre tag** in the HTML .The sendkeys is not working .IS there any other way we can enter text with out sendkeys option in selenium?

**The HTML before entering the text is**

```
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line ">
<span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
<span cm-text="">​</span>
</span>
```

**And After entered the text "rank(price) " the HTML is**

```
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line ">
<span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
<span class="cm-operator">rank</span>"("
<span class="cm-variable">price</span>")"
</span>
```

Comment: If you say 'is not working' does this mean that some exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre[@class='CodeMirror-line']"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='(222)222-2222';", wb);
```

Please let me know if that works for you. Webdriver provided the javscript implementation library so that we could use javascript to perform actions on browser which are not possible with with webdriver native API. And in web automation testing services we encountered many such issues where we have to go beyond webdriver native API and have to use javscript methods.

Comment: thank you Vel Guru, I fixed that by using selenium IDE and generate code to java. Then i find out my problem is calling the right xpath, it is like that: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='code-editor-container']/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/pre").click()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='code-editor-container']/div/div/textarea").send_keys(row)